# Flutter: Do sort and filter feature in Flutter or the back end?

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, asp.net-web-api

I am working on the sort and filter feature on my ecommerce application. Things like sort by price low to high, filter by brand name and colour.

Where is the best practice to do this feature? Should I do it on Flutter itself or done through my backend which is a ASP.NET Core API. I'm currently doing it on flutter, manipulating the product list returned from my API.

Tried methods such as

[image]

in Flutter. Wonder if it's the best practice

Answer (score 0):

It is better to sort on your server side. If you do it on client side, you will get unexpected results when you have pagination.